# Python pyautogui small program

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to make a small python program with pyautogui. So when i start it I am basically not going to access the screen without writing in the random password. 1st problem is that it keeps looping and lets me input as much as i want, and when I start it outside of IDLE I can not input anything. Can someone help me? Here's my code:

```
import pyautogui, sys

while True:
    pyautogui.moveTo(726, 380, duration=0.001)

de = input() 
pw = 'randompassword'

if de == pw:
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant help you too much but i can say a few things. `if de == pw:
    sys.exit()` needs to be indented to be checked in the while loop. Im not sure how you are going to take input while your code is busy. maybe if you ran 2 scripts? also word of advice ONCE YOU GET IT WORKING you may want to catch the KeyboardIntterupt to stop people from just closing your script and using your pc.

Comment: It is indented. Please read the [answer] page for further help on how to write better answers. 
Have fun answering and asking questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
import pyautogui as py
py.click(726, 380) #if you only want to move cursor use moveTo or move
while True:
    de=input()
    pw='randompassword'
    if de==pw:
        break
```